# Independent and Dependent Random Variables

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

Please give an example of 2 dependent random variables, X and Y such that P(X < Y)=1. 
Again, provide an example of 2 independent random variables, X and Y such that P(X < Y)=1

For the first part, I thought of the distribution, X~Uniform(0,1) and Y=2X which are clearly dependent

P(X < Y)=1
Would be P(2X-X > 0) which is P(X > 0)=1

I'm not sure if it is correct. The second part can be done similarly, using X~Unif(0,1) and Y~Unif(2,3).

I need better examples and I'm really not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. 
Please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.  If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I think you may have posted this before you had finished typing? Please edit to complete it.

Comment: @mdewey I'm sorry. There was a glitch.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It looks like a copy-paste error may have occurred, because the two parts of your question are identical.  What do you mean to ask?

Comment: Thank you for fixing it.  Could you explain what a "better" example might look like?  These seem just fine.

Comment: @whuber I wasn't sure if my reasoning was correct. Could you maybe give an example which does not involve Uniform Distribution?

Comment: Sure: consider the half-plane $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y \gt x\}.$  Define any probability measure you like on it.  Define the random variables $X(x,y)=x$ and $Y(x,y)=y.$  Their distributions cover every possible distribution that could answer one of the two parts of your question.